# Stop RxJS HTTP Polling after HTTP success response

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, polling, rxjs-observables

I have following code that mimics HTTP Requests polling.

```
  timeout:Observable<number> = timer(10000);

  startPollingStackblitz(arnId: string) {
    const poll:Observable<BuyingData[]> = of({}).pipe(
        mergeMap(_ => {
          console.log('polling...' + arnId);
          return of([]);
          // return this.service.getData(arnId);
        }),
        takeUntil(this.timeout),
        tap(_ => console.info('---waiting 2 secs to restart polling')),
        delay(2000),
        repeat(),
        tap(_ => console.info('---restarted polling')),
      );

    this.subscription = poll.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('subscribe...')
      if (data.length > 0) {
        console.log('timeout...');
        console.log(this.timeout);// I want to stop polling immediately before timer will elapse
      }
    });
  }
```

I want my polling stops sending HTTP Requests (it logs 'polling...' at this demo version) when server responds with **data.length > 0**. For some reason it continues to send Requests even after 10000ms timeout. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe use `retry` instead of `repeat`?

Comment: I am afraid not. Please see Example 2 from here https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/recipes/http-polling

Comment: `timer(10000)` will emit 0 after 10 seconds which is a falsy value.  So `takeUntil` won't stop the pipe. You can use an overload of `timer(10000,1)` to make it truthy or use the `timeout` operator instead merge it with a subject that you can fire in the subscription.

Comment: @Eldar doesn't matter if the stream under the `takeUntil` emits a falsy value, it's enough that it _emits_. Even a `Subject<void>` would do.

Comment: @Eldar thanks for you answer but `timer(10000,1)` did not help. Could you write a code snippet for your another theory with `timeout` operator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I understand you have two stopping conditions :

1. After a timeout (10sec)
2. When a response meets your condition (data.length > 0)

You can achieve this by combining `takeUntil`, `race`, and `timer` operators with a subject as below.

```
const stopper = new Subject(); // to stop emitting
const poll = of({}).pipe(
  mergeMap(_ =>
    fakeDelayedRequest().pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        console.error(e);
        return of(false);
      })
    )
  ),
  tap(write),
  tap(_ => console.info("---waiting 3 secs to restart polling")),
  delay(3000),
  tap(_ => console.info("---restarted polling")),
  repeat(),
  takeUntil(stopper.pipe(race(timer(10000)))) // this should be the last in the pipe
  // else `repeat` operator will be repeating without a condition.
);

poll.subscribe(_ => {
  const rnd = Math.random();
  if (rnd> 0.3) { // random stop condition
    console.log("closing !",rnd);
    stopper.next(); // emit the stop
  }
});
```

`takeUntil` will stop when the target observable emits a value. `timer` will emit a value after 10 secs. `race` will emit a value either from `stopper` or from `timer` which comes first.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-http-polling-mfhetx?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

`Repeat` returns an Observable that will resubscribe to the source stream when the source stream completes, in your case although  the source Observable completes (thanks to `takeUntil`), using repeat would resubcribe to source stream repeatedly

Instead of repeat your can try the following:

```
const poll :Observable<BuyingData[]> = interval(2000).pipe(
  exhaustMap(() => this.service.getData())
  takeUntil(this.timeout),
  takeWhile(data => data.length > 0),
);
```